# Unresolved exernal symbol

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file, class

I want to split my code into .cpp and .h files but I've never done it with classes. When compiling I get the following errors:

```
unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Worker::show(void)" (?show@Worker@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _main 

unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Worker::Worker(void)" (?show@Worker@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _main
```

here's my code:

```
f.h

#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Worker
{
public:

    void show();
    Worker();
    int i;
};

f.cpp

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include "f.h"
using namespace std;
void Worker::show() {
    cout << i;
}
Worker::Worker()
{
    int i = 0;
}

main.cpp

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include "f.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Worker w;
    w.i = 5;
    w.show();
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did u compile f.cpp ?

Comment: I did. (I used Local Windows Debugger in Visual Studio 2015, I believe it compiles every .cpp file in the open project,at least that's what it did before)

Comment: Verify that the file `f.cpp` (should probably be named worker.cpp) is in the project list.  Also verify that the `f` file is listed in the Linker Command Line.

Comment: @A.W. I don't see any problem in the code you posted.. it must be the way you are building ...

Comment: It wasn't in the project list, I don't know why sometimes the files are added automaticaly to the project and sometimes not. Will pay closer attention to this in the future. Thank you!